# Getting the multiple of two integers in C programming

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, multiplication

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a C program with two integer variables a and b. When the user types in these two variables, it should tell me if b is a multiple of a. Here's what I've done so far..

```
int main(void) /* standard header in c programming */
{
  int a;
  int b;

  printf("first number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("second number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &b);
}
```

I don't really know, if I should use "if..else" and what my algorithm should look like?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: How would you solve it with pen and paper?

Comment: hmm.. i'd take the value of a and divide it with b, right..?

Comment: @Magnacide Right, and what happens with remainder with integer division.

Comment: @self with remainder with integer division? what do you mean?

Comment: What happens with remainder when dividing integers in c.

Comment: @Magnacide What he's hinting at is, if you get any remainder, then it is not divisible. For example 5/2 gives remainder 1, thus 5 is not divisible by 2. While 4/2 gives remainder 0, so 4 is divisible by 2. So what you need to do is to write a program that checks if the reminder of `a/b` is 0 or not. In C, you get the remainder by using the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: @Lundin Now you might as well just write the code... or nevermind http://stackoverflow.com/a/24062544/2327831 /sarcasm

Comment: @self. Well, he was obviously not getting it, so it is either help him or go away. Writing the code and understanding the problem are unrelated tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to find out if one value is a multiple value of another value. If you can do a integer-division without remainder (remainder == 0), then it's a multiple.
See also [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int a, b;
  printf("first number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("second number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  if(b % a == 0){
    printf("b is a multiple of a");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: haven't grasp the use of % yet.. thanks guys. i'll learn more.

Comment: @user3121023 what's the remainder if you calculate 4/5 on paper?

Comment: @user3121023 4 % 5 = 4

Comment: @Magnacide If this answer solved your problem, please make sure to accept it as answer to your question (by clicking onto the checkmark on the left side from my post).